# how can i write a query for update data in sql?

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c

Currently, I write query for update data in iOS

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"update *from ericsson_review_form_field_table set value = %@ where fieldId = %@ and form_index = %d",strFValue,strFieldId,formIndex];
```

But it is not working.
Please tell me the sql query for update value.

Comment: Not working? Why not? What happens? What's supposed to happen? What is it supposed to update? Can you show the definitions? Was there an error code? If so, what was it? If not, how do you know it's `not working`? Can you show example data and expected results? Too much is missing to know what a correct answer would be.

Comment: My query was wrong therefore i had got problem to update data. now my query is given below answer by me. user2338816

Comment: That's understood. But we need to know what you want the query to do. We know you want it to "update" something, but we don't know what should be updated. And if we don't know the table and column definitions, we won't know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you made a mistake in writing query to update any record, just try it

```
NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE EMPLOYEES set name = '%@', department = '%@', age = '%@' WHERE id = ?",
                                employee.name,
                                employee.department,
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", employee.age]];
```

Answer (score 1):

First Google and then ask..See below example for update

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1
WHERE [condition];

UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET ADDRESS = 'Pune', SALARY = 1000.00;

NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update table_name SET name='%@'  where regno='1000'"];
```

Hope it helps you....

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to update record in table is as bellow

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.col1 = table1.col1, 
table2.col2 = table1.col2,
...
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.memberid = table2.memberid
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently my code is

```
 - (BOOL)updateReviewFields:(NSString *)strFieldId andFormIndex:(int)formIndex withFValue:(NSString *)strFValue{
sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
NSString *query;
if(sqlite3_open([[appDelegate databasePath] UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK){
   query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"update ericsson_review_form_field_table set value = %@ where fieldId = %@ and form_index = %d",strFValue,strFieldId,formIndex];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)
       == SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [strFieldId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 13, [strFValue UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
       if(sqlite3_step(statement))
            return YES;
        else
            return NO;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
return NO;
```

}

and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You posted a code sample:

```
- (BOOL)updateReviewFields:(NSString *)strFieldId andFormIndex:(int)formIndex withFValue:(NSString *)strFValue{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    NSString *query;
    if(sqlite3_open([[appDelegate databasePath] UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK){
       query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"update ericsson_review_form_field_table set value = %@ where fieldId = %@ and form_index = %d",strFValue,strFieldId,formIndex];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)
           == SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [strFieldId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 13, [strFValue UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           if(sqlite3_step(statement))
                return YES;
            else
                return NO;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return NO;
}
```

I don't see how the above could possibly work.

1. You're using `sqlite3_bind_text`, but you don't have any `?` placeholders in your SQL to bind to. (You should check the return code from your `sqlite3_bind_text` calls and I'd be shocked if they're returning `SQLITE_OK`.)
2. You're binding the first item and the thirteenth item. The latter bind call, to the thirteenth `?`, certainly wouldn't work unless you had at least thirteen `?` placeholders.
3. You're returning immediately after calling `sqlite3_step`, never hitting your `sqlite3_finalize` statement and you'd undoubtedly leak memory as a result. You'd also never close the database if you got to these `return` statements after `sqlite3_step`.
4. You're testing `if (sqlite3_step(...))`. That doesn't make sense, because `sqlite3_step` always returns a non-zero value (either `SQLITE_DONE` upon success or some non-zero error code on error).
5. I'd suggest logging `sqlite3_errmsg` if any of the SQLite calls fail.
6. I might suggest changing the return value of the method to be the number of rows that were updated. This way, you can differentiate between (a) successful update; (b) no rows updated (but no errors); and (c) a failure. I might return negative value on error, zero if no rows matched the `WHERE` criteria, and a positive value, *n*, if *n* rows were successfully updated. I use `sqlite3_changes` to determine how many rows were updated.
7. Finally, I'd seriously advise against using `stringWithFormat` to build your SQL (at least if the string values include any user-provided input, because you expose yourself to quoting and/or SQL injection problems).

So, instead, I'd suggest:

```
/** Update fields
 *
 * @param strFieldId The fieldId column string value
 * @param formIndex The form_index integer value
 * @param strFValue The string to which the `value` column should be updated.
 *
 * @return Returns the number of rows updated. Return negative value on failure. Return zero if no rows matched the WHERE criteria.
 */
- (int)updateReviewFields:(NSString *)strFieldId andFormIndex:(int)formIndex withFValue:(NSString *)strFValue {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSString *databasePath = [appDelegate databasePath];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    int rowCount = -1;
    int rc;

    if ((rc = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open database: %@ (%ld)", databasePath, (long)rc);
        return rowCount;
    }

    const char *query = "update ericsson_review_form_field_table set value = ? where fieldId = ? and form_index = ?";

    if ((rc = sqlite3_prepare(database, query, -1, &statement, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_prepare fail: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(database), (long)rc);
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return rowCount;
    }

    if ((rc = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [strFValue UTF8String], -1, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_bind_text 1 fail: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(database), (long)rc);
    } else if ((rc = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [strFieldId UTF8String], -1, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_bind_text 2 fail: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(database), (long)rc);
    } else if ((rc = sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 3, formIndex)) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_bind_int 3 fail: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(database), (long)rc);
    } else if ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_step fail: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(database), (long)rc);
    } else {
        rowCount = sqlite3_changes(database);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    sqlite3_close(database);

    return rowCount;
}
```

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't suggest opening and closing the database with every call, though. But I left that in my code sample because that's what your original snippet did, but I'd generally advise opening once and only closing when the app terminates.